# Plot a csv data as a map - Python

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I have to read a csv file that represents a map.
My csv is something like this (piece of data):

```
"","x","y","sim1","sim2","sim3","sim4","sim5","sim6","sim7","sim8","sim9","sim10","sim11","sim12"
"1",181180,333740,5.56588745117188,6.29487752914429,7.4835410118103,5.75873327255249,6.62183284759521,5.81478500366211,4.85671949386597,5.90418815612793,6.32611751556396,6.99649047851562,6.52076387405396,5.68944215774536
"2",181140,333700,6.36264753341675,6.5217604637146,6.16843748092651,5.55328798294067,7.00429201126099,6.43625402450562,6.17744159698486,6.72836923599243,6.38574266433716,6.81451606750488,6.68060827255249,6.14339065551758
"3",181180,333700,6.16541910171509,6.44704437255859,7.51744651794434,5.46270132064819,6.8890323638916,6.46842670440674,6.07698059082031,6.2140531539917,6.43774271011353,6.21923875808716,6.43355655670166,5.90692138671875
```

Where the first column shows how many pair of x/y coordinates I have, x and y been longitude/latitude as simN the value of a property for the simulation #N.

Using d3, I can quickly read this csv and show it like a map that it represents:

```
d3.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11442023/Geostatistic/sim100.csv", function(error, data) {
if (error) {  //If error is not null, something went wrong.
    console.log("Error loading sim100 data.");
    console.log(error);  //Log the error.
} else {      //If no error, the file loaded correctly. Yay!
    console.log("Data sim100 loaded successfully!");
    //Include other code to execute after successful file load here
    simulationDataset = data;
    scaleX = d3.scale.linear().domain([d3.min(simulationDataset, function(d) {return d.x;}), d3.max(simulationDataset, function(d) { return d.x; })]);
    scaleY = d3.scale.linear().domain([d3.min(simulationDataset, function(d) {return d.y;}), d3.max(simulationDataset, function(d) { return d.y; })]);
    }
});
```

[image]

I've already save this in a numpy array:

```
np.loadtxt("Data/sim.csv", delimiter=',', usecols=range(1,4), skiprows=1)
```

In Python, I don't know how could I achieve this. Moreover, besides plotting the map for a simulation, I have to save this is a matrix for future work that I have to do. But, as x and y are longitude/latitude, I don't have the points like (0,0) (0,1) (0,2), i.e, like a simple matrix.  But I don't know if there is something like what I mentioned above to scale the domain.

I thought about finding the max/min latitude and longitude to define my matrix size, and them make some calculus to fits each pair longitude/latitude into this structure. But this not seems to be a good approach to me and, have seen everything that I saw that Python can do, I suppose that exists a better solution.

What I would like most it's to know if there is a "magic" function that saves this data in a matrix that makes sense (doing the transformation for all longitude/latitude index and save the value at this index in this matrix) or if I have to do what I thought, find the min/max and work with translations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tip: usually when I want to figure out how to plot something using `matplotlib`, I go to the [gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) and look for something similar.

Comment: Can you show your R code?

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to write something fairly easily that parses that CSV and inputs the data into a numpy array. Numpy is one of the most common modules for scientific data computation. From there, you could use matplotlib or mayavi to provide a graphical representation of your data.

Comment: I already put it in a numpy array. But besides plot this (which I couldn't do so far), I have to save this into a matrix.